# How can I tell what the most recent kernel update is for 22.04?

Tags: kernel, updates, update-manager

I am currently running 5.15.0-56.62-generic. How can I tell whether this is the most up-to-date update that should be made available to me via the software updater?

Comment: You've not said how you want to view it; myself I prefer a CLI enquiry but using a browser you can look with https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=linux-generic or https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-generic-hwe-22.04&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop defaults to the HWE kernel stack; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server defaults to the GA kernel stack; *flavors* vary depending on installation media, but you didn't specify which 22.04 you're using...)

Comment: Thanks, I'm running desktop, so as best I can tell from your searches, 5.15.0.56.54 is the latest, yet I've got 5.15.0.56.62. Not sure I understand that, but I suppose there isn't anything newer at least.